# How to force letsencrypt authorize domain via HTTP?

Tags: c#, ssl

I use ACMESharp library to deal with letsencrypt API.

Made following steps:

1. `Register()`
2. `UpdateRegistration` - agreed with ToC
3. `var authState = cl.AuthorizeIdentifier(domain);`  - get identifier here, status 'pending'

I have a page that displays token for domain:

```
~/.well-known/acme-challenge/{file}
```

What do I need to do next?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

```
        string chType = AcmeProtocol.CHALLENGE_TYPE_HTTP;

        AuthorizeChallenge chAns = cl.GenerateAuthorizeChallengeAnswer(authState, chType);

        authState.Challenges = new List<AuthorizeChallenge> {chAns};

        // update HTML with authState.Challenges[n].Value

        chAns = cl.SubmitAuthorizeChallengeAnswer(authState, chType);

        cl.RefreshAuthorizeChallenge(authState, chType);
```

And finally here we have VALID domain :)